# PowerQuery: DataSource.Error is there a work around to fix this error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a table Dashboad.xlsx from my Source file with this query

= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\G019\OneDrive - Client\P_MC\1 Client File\Official List_1Drive.xlsx"), null, true)

The issue is in refreshing Dashboad.xlsx when my Source file is open or used by other users.

I have this error "DataSource.Error: The process cannot be access the file.......because it is being used by another process."

Is there a workaround to address this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help.